# Positioning content of div independent of child divs

Tags: html, css

Consider this example html:

```
<body>
<div id="background">
        <div id="area1">.....</div>
        <div id="area2">.....</div>
        <div id="area3">.....</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have my area1, area2 and area3 divs all positioned where I want them using Twitter's bootstrap helper library.

I now want to place a background picture behind all these. However, I want the background image to placed at a specific location. So I've set my css for background with the URL of my image. The image only takes up the space that the 3 divs below occupy.

If I change the positioning of the background div, then the other 3 areas move with it.

Therefore, I'm wondering, how can I position my background image in a specific location, without altering the other divs positioning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't move the div - change the position of the background picture using `background-position`.  You can specify precisely the position in pixels (`x y`), percentage points(`x% y%`), or anchor it by the top/middle/bottom and left/center/right points.  For example:

```
#background {
  background-image: url('cat.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't realize there was such a property!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but I think something like this would help

```
#background div {background-image:url(image.jpg);
#area1{background-position: left top}
#area2{background-position: center top}
#area3{background-position: right top}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the css property `background-position`: [Codertools.com](http://www.codertools.com/css_help_guide/css_background-position.aspx) / [sitepoint.com](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position)

e.g.:

```
background-position: 50px 100px;
```